# Conditional mean and scatter plot

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataframe with four columns

Year- 1988 or 2010

Marriage- 5 to 1 depending (strong opposition to strong support)

Age

Dummy- Value 0 for 1, 2, 3. Value 1 for 4 and 5.

```
  year marriage age dummy
1 1988        5  56     1
2 1988        3  40     0
3 1988        3  29     0
4 1988        4  25     1
5 1988        4  48     1
6 1988        4  27     1
```

I want to plot oppossition to marriage equality. To do this, I want to calculate the mean opposition level of each reported age, do a plot for 1988 and overlay it with 2010. However, I am having issues conditioning my mean to both age and year,  and I also want to see if there is a more efficient way to do this.

This is what I was trying to do:

```
uniqueyear <- unique(marriage$age)

sort(uniqueyear)

mean(marriage$marriage[marriage$age %in% 18 & marriage$year %in% 1988])
```

This code works if I only want to condition for age, but doesn't work when I add year. I get unexpected symbol error.

I would like to know if someone could help me understand why the double conditioning doesn't work, and also if there are any ideas to get the mean and plot faster than doing the mean for everything, make it a dataframe, and then do my scatterplot.

Thank you!

Comment: I couldn't replicate the "unexpected symbol error", probably there's no `with(marriage, any(age == 18 & year == 1988))`? Anyway, your manual approach would lead to tons of repeated lines of code and I suggest to get into sophisticated functions for sake of efficiency, see e.g. my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you want to aggregate your data by age and year, which you could achieve with `tapply`. The result may be `barplot`ted very easily. I use different example data with two sorts of years.

```
agg <- with(dat, tapply(marriage, list(age, year), mean))
barplot(proportions(agg, 2), beside=T, main="Plot", col=2:6, ylim=c(0, .45))
legend("topright", rownames(agg), col=2:6, pch=15, title="Age", bty="n")
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(year = c(1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 
1988, 1988, 1988, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2010), age = c(28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 
32L, 32L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L), 
    dummy = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1), marriage = c(1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L)), out.attrs = list(
    dim = c(year = 2L, age = 10L), dimnames = list(year = c("year=1988", 
    "year=2010"), age = c("age=28", "age=28", "age=29", "age=29", 
    "age=30", "age=30", "age=31", "age=31", "age=32", "age=32"
    ))), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 
19L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```